# How to commit single files with JGit

Tags: eclipse, jgit

even it is not recommended, I use for specific approach a:

```
git commit -m 'xxxx' file 1 file2
```

Where both files, that are indexed and changed will be part of the commit.
But not e.g. file3 and file4 that are changed too - but not named in the commit.

Question: How can I do this using JGit!
Even Eclipse offers this - but I did not find any approach to to this using JGit (porcelain).

Answer (score 5):

Without having tried myself, there is a `setOnly` method on `CommitCommand`. According to the documentation you should be able to call

```java
git.commit().setOnly("file1").setOnly("file2").setMessage("...").call();
```

and the command would add `file1` and `file2` to a temporary index and then commit in one go.

If that doesn't work you can still use the `AddCommand` to add individual files to the index and then commit:

```java
git.add().setFilepattern("file1").addFilepattern("file2").call();
git.commit().setMessage("...").call();
```

If files were already added, you can reset the index before adding files like so:

```java
git.reset().setMode(ResetType.MIXED).call();
```

Comment: So It was the .setOnly feature I was not aware. So it is solved!